# Emanation by the One according to Plotinus

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, mind, neoplatonism, plotinus

How is Mind (Nous) formed from "the One” according to Plotinus?

What is the mechanism of this phenomenon?

Why is it Nous, and not the Soul or something else, that is the first emanation?

Comment: @I recommend https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plotinus/#ThreFundPrinPlotMeta Chapter 2. But I doubt that Plotinus answers your question with the desired precision and attention to detail.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But the answers here could be more useful.

Comment: You need to do your own homework. It's part of the process of learning to think.

Comment: @ggkhj Possibly helpful is the following link to a similar question and its answer https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/52726/what-is-the-difference-between-the-hypostasis-soul-the-world-soul-and-individu?rq=1

Comment: There is no "process" or "mechanism", see  [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/Entries/neoplatonism/#AbsCon):"*To be sure, Consciousness (or Intellect) somehow emerges from the activity of the First, but calling this a process of emanation, with its obviously materialist connotations, is misleading. The Neoplatonists used the words “procession and return” (prohodos and epistrophê), which, as spatial metaphors, are not much better either... In essence, there is no process of generation or production; nothing material or spatial is happening; no agent exerts its influence on a patient.*"

Comment: See [Plotinus](https://iep.utm.edu/plotinus/#SH2c): There is the One and the One “‘overflows’ and its excess begets an other than itself” [and ] this ‘other’ is the Intelligence (Nous), the source of the realm of multiplicity. The Intelligence (Nous) is the true first principle of all existents.

Comment: Thank you for your answers